# AppleScript: how to escape control characters in a string

Tags: applescript

I'm wondering if one can **escape control characters and put in a string of text** in AppleScript. For instance, does AppleScript support hex escape codes? If so, how? (I Googled but found nothing, sorry if this is a trivial question.)

---

### Context

For some task I want to write a `^D` (`\x04`) to iTerm2 to signal the end of stdin. Here's the skeleton of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "iTerm"
    create window with default profile
    tell the current window
        tell the current session
            # write some text -- launch an interactive program
            # write some text to stdin, typically from the clipboard

            ##### PROBLEM HERE
            # close stdin -- write text ^D? How to achieve this?
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I don't want to use a keystroke instead since that would require additional privilege. Is there a better way without escaping `^D`? Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OS X 10.5 and later, use "character id", for example:

```
set ctrlD to character id 4
```

The number should correspond to the Unicode code point value of the character, which, for characters 0-127, is the same as its ASCII value.

On 10.4.11 and earlier, use "ascii character", for example:

```
set ctrlD to ascii character 4
```

The number should be the ASCII value of the character. This form has been deprecated by Apple since Mac OS X 10.5, but still works as of OS X 10.10.1.

You should then be able to treat "ctrlD" like any other string. Haven't specifically tried it with iTerm, but if the question is how to get a non-printable character into an AppleScript string, this is the way.

Comment: Thanks, this exactly answers what I'm asking! One more question though: I found `ASCII character` in [Apple's commands reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW21) (sorry for missing it earlier), and it is deprecated in AppleScript 2.0 in favor of the `id` property of the `text` class. However, the `id` property is read-only, so how do I achieve the same effect with the `text` class?

Comment: Good point; I was unaware of that! I've updated the answer to use the currently supported form. Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-10_5/RN-10_5.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So it's that simple — I should have read the manual more carefully...

Comment: Well, the thing about AppleScript is that it always looks simple once you know how, and it's rarely simple until you do.

Comment: I mean, if I read the manual more carefully I would have picked up the example "`character id 65` returns `"A"`" in it... Anyway, you're right. (Or are you with the "it always looks simple" part? AppleScript might look conceptually simple at times, but it's always syntactically clumsy. From my experience with real programming languages, it takes a genius to invent a language as horrible as AppleScript...)

Answer (score 1):

To send the command, you can:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 2 using {shift down, Control down}
```

Comment: Note that I mentioned specifically "I don't want to use a keystroke instead since that would require additional privilege".

Comment: Sending a key code normally does not require any special permissions for the app you're working in. Also, I apologize I had a hard time following exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I have the impression that emulating a key press requires the privilege of assistive devices. Maybe I'm wrong. Will test later. Btw, would you please comment on what's hard to follow? Is the wording unclear? Escaping characters is very basic stuff in every programming language, so I fail to see why this question is hard to understand.

Comment: Okay, I was able to confirm that keystroke with System Events does not require assistive access. I've upvoted the answer, but I'll leave it open to see if direct escaping is possible.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "direct escaping". That's what I meant earlier by your language not making sense. By using system events, you are DIRECTLY sending the escape character you are wanting. What more are you wanting?

Comment: I asked for a **character**, which is abstract, not a **keystroke**, which is concrete and limited. (For example, you can put a character on the clipboard, but not a keystroke.)

Comment: Also, the phrase "direct escaping" appeared for the first time *after* you remarked that my question doesn't make sense...